# The result of "size" command in linux and the values of text&edata&end are different

Tags: c, linux, process

The code is

```
/* test_etext.c */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern char etext, edata, end;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid, ppid;

    pid = getpid();
    ppid = getppid();

    printf("%ld\t%ld\t%ld\n", &etext, &edata-&etext, &end-&edata);

    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and run it like this

```
gcc -o test_etext test_etext.c

./test_etext
4196125 2099507 8

size ./test_etext
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
1532        592       8    2132     854 ./test_etext
```

The question is that why the segment data between "&edata-&etext" and "data" are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course they are different! Did you even read the manpage, [`man 3 etext`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/etext.3.html)?

- `etext` is the first address past the end of the text (code),
- `edata` is the first address past the end of the initialized data, and
- `end` is the first address past the end of the uninitialized data (bss)

Due to address space randomization, you should not assume anything about the layout of the above in memory. Therefore, *their differences convey no reliable information*.

To calculate the respective sizes of the text, initialized data, and uninitialized data, you'd need to find the initial address of the same first (and substract that from the corresponding end address).

Since you tagged your question Linux, I'd personally just query the kernel's opinion, by reading the `/proc/self/statm` pseudo-file. If you need more detailed information (like details for dynamically-loaded libraries), or the information that matches the `size` command output, read `/proc/self/smaps` or `/proc/self/maps` pseudo-files. These are all described in detail in [`man 5 proc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

For executable ELF files -- similar to how `size` or `objdump` work, for example --, use either existing utilities, or existing libraries at least.

Comment: Thanks, the word "past" that make me confused. I thought the position of end of text segment and etext is continuous.